# How do I show items in Google Docs' "Home" category?

Tags: google-drive

I'd like to start using the Home View to keep things I work on at the front whenever I log in, however I don't know how.  If I drag any existing files onto it, nothing shows up.  If I manually select it, the actions I can take with it include "*Don't* show this in Home", and if I do that, then follow it up with "Show this in Home" (trying to refresh it or something), nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding how the Home view works.

The Home view displays **all** of your files and documents. Because of this, the only thing you can do is *hide* items from the home view.

For clarification, the All Items view displays **all* of your files including those that you have hidden from the Home view.

Both views exclude files or folders that are in the bin.

See [this Google Documents Help article](https://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=1107581&topic=1382883) for further information.